# pentaho data integration: Executing PDI the BI Server or with carte?

Tags: etl, pentaho, data-integration

I'm working on a project with pentaho. I'm gonna use the whole community edition solution.

I'll have jobs and transformations that will be launch by user for some (so with PDI on their computer), and automatically for others.

I'm wondering if I can install PDI on the server side (with the BI server and DW) and schedule the automated job/transfo with it?

There is also the carte part that permit to execute the jobs remotely but I don't see the difference with my solution above.

thks for your help

Comment: I have the same question. I need to do automatically data integration jobs. But the Pentaho Data Integration is a desktop tool. I'm searching for information, but I can't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like carte is just if you want to execute job (that is on a computer) on the server (remotely), so mainly for big job I guess.

Otherwise to schedule automatically you put PDI on the server and use your favourite scheduler (cron ...) that'll launch the kjb file

I'd just like to know if I can execute a job on my server when a file (xml) is added on the repository and how to do it?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this? I'm currently searching to find out what the community-equivalent tools are.